# How to get position of scroll indicator ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiscrollview

How to get position of scroll indicator ? So that I can move small view with scroll indicator..In UITableview/scrollview.

Comment: You wanted to ask how to make login like in facebook using iphone , where view moves up when keyboard appears ?

Comment: your requirement is not clear. but anyway contentOffset tells you where you are.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this `tableView.contentOffset.y;`. This gives you your scrollView position.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to scroll your textfield when keyboard appears use this line in textfieldShouldBeginEditing method

```
  [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, y) animated:hasAppeared];
```

you can use it anywhere to move ur table to that set point

Answer (score 0):

This will give you centre of the scroll indicator

centre = ((scrollView.contentOffset.y + (scrollView.bounds.size.height / 2)) / scrollView.contentSize.height ) * scrollView.bounds.size.height